# Grunt uncss task for nested classes

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, uncss

I'm using `grunt-uncss` with my `AngularJs` app and I'd like to know if it's possible to specify a nested class in the options to be ignored.

For example, my css output when using Angular animations would be something like this:

```
.button.ng-enter {...}
```

And in the options I would have to specify it like this:

```
options: {
    ignore: ['.button.ng-enter']
},
```

It's ok if i have just a few.. But in a large application I would have to specify it explicit for all the use cases.

Is there a way to declare only the `.ng-enter` and process it for all the use cases, even when nesting with other classes?